# How to merge two xml input variables using xslt 2.0 with out for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

We need process each `employeeNumber` from InputVar1, fetch the corresponding department values from InputVar2, and show the below output format map to OuputVar. We don't need to show employee records which are not present in InputVar1.

We should use xslt2.0 without using for-each loop

**InputVar1.xml**

```
<Employees>
    <List>
    <emplyeeNumber>123</employeeNumber>
    <employeeName>abc</emploeeName>
    </List>
    <List>
    <emplyeeNumber>453</employeeNumber>
    <employeeName>cde</emploeeName>
    </List>
    <List>
    <emplyeeNumber>678</employeeNumber>
    <employeeName>efg</emploeeName>
    </List>
    </Employees>
```

**InputVar2.xml**

```
 <Departs>
   <List>
     <emplyeeNumber>123</employeeNumber>
     <departName>fin</departName>
     <departId>10</departId>
   </List>
   <List>
     <emplyeeNumber>919</employeeNumber>
     <departName>adm</departName>
     <departId>20</departId>
   </List>
   <List>
     <emplyeeNumber>453</employeeNumber>
     <departName>hr</departName>
     <departId>30</departId>
   </List>
 </Departs>
```

**OutputVar:**

```
<WriteFile>
  <LinesRecordSet>
    <LinesRecord>
    <emplyeeNumber>123</employeeNumber>
    <departName>fin</departName>
    <departId>10</departId>
    <employeeName>abc</emploeeName>
  </LinesRecord>
  <LinesRecord>
    <emplyeeNumber>453</employeeNumber>
    <departName>hr</departName>
    <departId>30</departId>
    <employeeName>cde</emploeeName>
    </LinesRecord>
  <LinesRecord>
    <emplyeeNumber>678</employeeNumber>
    <departName></departName>
    <departId></departId>
    <employeeName>efg</emploeeName>
    </LinesRecord>
  </LinesRecordSet>
<WriteFile>
```

Comment: I have used for-each loop and xpath condition but getting performance issues.

Comment: Ask how to do a task, not how to do to a task using X or not using Y. FYI, `xsl:for-each` is not  a "loop" and it's not likely the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: Note that your text talks about `employeeNumber` but your samples seems to consistently use the odd name `emplyeeNumber`

Comment: P.S. All 3 of your documents have syntax errors (e.g. `emplyeeNumber` in start-tag vs. `employeeNumber` in end-tag. The purpose of posting these documents is to allow us to test our answers. Please show more consideration for the people trying to help you and fix your mistakes before posting.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. In your example, you could do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="dept" match="List" use="employeeNumber" />
<xsl:param name="dept-doc">path/to/InputVar2.xml</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <WriteFile>
        <LinesRecordSet>
            <xsl:for-each select="List">
                <LinesRecord>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="employeeNumber"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('dept', employeeNumber, document($dept-doc))/(departName, departId)"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="employeeName"/>
                </LinesRecord>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </LinesRecordSet>
    </WriteFile>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: do we have any other solution without using key function please.

Comment: The above InputVar1 and InputVar2 are 2 variables not xml files.

Comment: @sum I am afraid I don't know what you mean by "variables". You will have to make your own adjustments to your scenario. As for other solution, I see no reason to look for it.

Comment: @sum Why do you want a solution that avoids using the perfect tool for the job in hand?

Comment: @sum, in XSLT 2.0 and later the third argument to the `key` function can be any node rooted in a tree so whether you have e.g. `<xsl:variable name="inputVar2" select="doc('file2.xml')"/>` or `<xsl:variable name="inputVar2"><Departs>..</Departs></xsl:variable>`, the `$inputVar2` variable reference can be passed just fine as the third argument to the `key` function.